# Why is debugging VueJS so flaky in VSCode

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I have been using VSCode for a few months and have not been able to find a way to consistently debug a simple VueJS app. The main issue I keep encountering is the `Unbound breakpoint` whereby the breakpoints I set are unreachable.

I have tried the many `launch.json` configs including the ones below with no success:

```
{
    "name": "Launch Chrome",
    "request": "launch",
    "type": "pwa-chrome",
    "url": "http://localhost:8080",
    "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
},

{
    "name": "Attach hm",
    "port": 9229,
    "request": "attach",
    "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**"],
    "type": "pwa-node",
    "address": "localhost:8080",
    "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src"
}
```

A few weeks ago I stumbled on the following config which magically solved my problem and I was happily debugging for days:

```
{
    "type": "chrome",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
    "url": "http://localhost:8080",
    "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src",
    "breakOnLoad": true,
    "sourceMaps": true
}
```

After taking a few days off coding, I came back to VSCode yesterday, there was the `1.47.2` update waiting. Did that, wrote a few lines of code, tried debugging like i was doing before and boom! the `Unbound breakpoint` problem from hell returned.

Check my commits, no changes to launch.json, no new install, updates whatsoever.

Why on Earth diid this thing stop working???

One thing to note is that I can perfectly debug in VSCode the server portion of my app (a node/express REST server) with no problem at all.

Very frustrating and I really do not want to go back to debugging using Chrome's DevTools.

Could anyone help?

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced may times similar issues.
Have you found a solution?
My `launch.json` file is:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "vuejs: chrome",
      "url": "http://localhost:3000",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src",
      "breakOnLoad": true,
      "pathMapping": {
        "/_karma_webpack_": "${workspaceFolder}"
      },
      "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
        "webpack:/*": "${webRoot}/*",
        "/./*": "${webRoot}/*",
        "/src/*": "${webRoot}/*",
        "/*": "*",
        "/./~/*": "${webRoot}/node_modules/*"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Most of times it works but I still experience weird behaviors.
Also you should always start VS Code from within the folder containing the VUE project (outside /src).